# With clause not working with union

Tags: oracle

My query result is a union of several queries. I am facing the below error when I use WITH clause within a union. Any ideas why?

```
select column1 from TABLE_A
union
with abcd as (select * from TABLE_B)
    select column2 from TABLE_A A, abcd 
    where abcd.m_reference = A.m_reference
```

> ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
>   32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
>   *Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
>              1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
>              2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
>              3. WITH clause can't sepecified within parentheses.
>   *Action:   correct query and retry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just define the CTE first, before the actual `UNION` query.  Then use it as you would a regular table:

```
with abcd as (select * from TABLE_B)
select column1 from TABLE_A
union
select column2
from TABLE_A A
inner join abcd
    on abcd.m_reference = A.m_reference
```

You can use multiple CTE as follows:

```
with cte1 AS (...),
     cte2 AS (...)
select * from ...
```

Comment: Works in case  there is only one query i want to union with "with". what if there are multiple?

Answer (score 14):

Encapsulate your WITH statement in a dummy select.

```
select column1 from TABLE_A
union
select * from (
  with abcd as (select * from TABLE_B)
    select column2 from TABLE_A A, abcd 
    where abcd.m_reference = A.m_reference
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating it is the way to go if you have multiple WITHs; for example I just had to do this monstrosity to quickly pull in data from ID numbers from an Excel sheet

```
select * from (
   with childvendor as (
    select vendornumber, name From vendor where vendornumber = '0000800727'
   )
   select 
    v.vendornumber as parentvendor, 
    v.name as parentname,
    cv.vendornumber as childvendor,
    cv.name as childname
   From 
    vendor v, childvendor cv
   where 
    v.vendornumber = '0000800004'
) 
UNION ALL
select * from (
   with childvendor as (
    select vendornumber, name From vendor where vendornumber = '0000800042'
   )
   select 
    v.vendornumber as parentvendor, 
    v.name as parentname,
    cv.vendornumber as childvendor,
    cv.name as childname
   From 
    vendor v, childvendor cv
   where 
     v.vendornumber = '0000800035'
)
```

And so on